# Why are string indexes converted to integers when using a foreach loop in PHP?

Tags: php, associative-array

When I loop through an associative array the string indexes are converted to integers.

Why does this happen?

```
$day_of_the_week = array(
        "1" => 'Monday',
        "2" => 'Tuesday',
        "3" => 'Wednesday',
        "4" => 'Thursday',
        "5" => 'Friday',
        "6" => 'Saturday',
        "7" => 'Sunday'
    );

foreach($day_of_the_week as $index => $value){
    echo "Index: $index<br />Type: " . gettype($index) . "<br />Value:$value<br /><br />";
}
```

Output:

```
Index: 1
Type: integer
Value: Monday

Index: 2
Type: integer
Value: Tuesday

Index: 3
Type: integer
Value: Wednesday

Index: 4
Type: integer
Value: Thursday

Index: 5
Type: integer
Value: Friday

Index: 6
Type: integer
Value: Saturday

Index: 7
Type: integer
Value: Sunday
```

This causes problems when using the strpos($haystack, $needle) function because the $needle parameter: "Is converted to an integer and applied as the ordinal value of a character."

A simple solution is to throw the strval function into the strpos function:

```
strpos($haystack,strval($needle))
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strval.php

Comment: It's not because of the foreach loop. Read the docs about arrays.

Comment: why are you even using strpos on the array? there are array functions of find the key from the value and visa-versa, If you tell us what your actually trying to achieve, we can give you a better answer

Comment: just typecast it anyway.

Comment: @dagon in a database the selected options are stored like this 1|2|3|4 so looping through form elements and searching if the checkbox value is in the selected value using strpos the way it was decided to be done.

Comment: It is because PHP is a Dynamic programming language: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming_language and thus `var_dump('123' == 123);` is *true*

Comment: @Ben A) you should normalize the data and B) i dont see how that relates to the above code